# Make TabView Background Transparent

Tags: swift, swiftui, opacity, tabview

Views in SwiftUI have a transparent background by default. This usually means that they have a white background because that's the default background color of your app. However, this also means that you can use a `ZStack` to change the background color of your entire app and that color will show through all your views unless you explicitly set their own background color:

```
struct Main: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.orange.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

            // Sub-view inlined
            VStack {
                Text("Hello World")
                Button("Press Me", action: { print("Pressed") })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

The problem I have run into is that this is not true for a `TabView`:

```
struct Main: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.orange.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

            // Sub-view inlined
            TabView {
                VStack {
                    Text("Hello World")
                    Button("Press Me", action: { print("Pressed") })
                }.tabItem {
                    Text("First Page")
                }
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

The `TabView` blocks the background color:

[image]

I can change the background color of the subview, but if I make it transparent, the background is white again instead of showing the underlying color in the `ZStack`. I've also tried sundry other ways to make the `TabView` transparent, such as setting its background to `Color.clear`, but to no avail.

**TL;DR**

Is it possible to make a `TabView` transparent instead of white?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The hosting view of every tab has system background color (which is opaque).

[image: demo1]

Here is possible workaround. Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14

[image: demo]

```
struct BackgroundHelper: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        let view = UIView()
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            // find first superview with color and make it transparent
            var parent = view.superview
            repeat {
                if parent?.backgroundColor != nil {
                    parent?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
                    break
                }
                parent = parent?.superview
            } while (parent != nil)
        }
        return view
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {}
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.orange.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

            // Sub-view inlined
            TabView {
                VStack {
                    Text("Hello World")
                    Button("Press Me", action: { print("Pressed") })
                }
                .background(BackgroundHelper())  // add to each tab if needed
                .tabItem {
                    Text("First Page")
                }
                Text("Second")
                    .background(BackgroundHelper())  // add to each tab if needed
                    .tabItem {
                        Text("Second Page")
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked when the first tab item was selected, but even with the background helper added to all items, the rest did not get a transparent background. 

Comment: Every tab has own background, so yes, it should be added, if needed, to every tab. What do you mean by *the rest*?

Comment: I added the custom background to all the tab item views. The view for the first tab item has a transparent background, but the views for the rest of the tab items (I have 4 total) do not have a transparent background, despite me adding the modifier to them.

Comment: Just retested - works fine. Make sure you added modifier *before* `.tabItem` as updated.

Comment: This is weird. I'm using the `.tag` modifier so I can connect each tab item to an enum case. When I remove this modifier, it starts working.

Comment: Never mind. I think I'm just going crazy. It's working now. Must have messed something up before without realizing it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: The view flashes when first switched tab because the modifier needs the dispatch which skips a frame (but removing the dispatch causes it to have no effect) - any solution to that? Thanks!